# Creating topological spaces with portals

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I'm trying to rigorously describe an object that I'm calling a "portal". The situation is easiest to describe in two dimension.

I start with a line segment $pq$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to remove the relative interior of $pq$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$, pull apart the opening and consider the new "boundary" which I will denote by an oriented path $\overrightarrow{pq}$ and $\overrightarrow{qp}$. Along each of $\overrightarrow{pq}$ and $\overrightarrow{qp}$ I want to glue a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The result will be the original $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two additional $\mathbb{R}^2$ glued along  $\overrightarrow{pq}$ and $\overrightarrow{qp}$. However, here's the catch, I want $pq$ to act as a "portal" meaning that if I consider a path entering from $\overrightarrow{pq}$ I enter the copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that I glued along $\overrightarrow{pq}$ and I can only get back to the original $\mathbb{R}^2$ via that same entrance. Likewise, if I consider a path that enters along $\overrightarrow{qp}$ I should enter the copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that I glued along that boundary.

It should be noted that if I can do this construction without removing $pq$ that would be fine as well. I just don't know another way to separate the segment into two distinct parts.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ I have a smooth orientable patch of surface $\sigma$. (homeomorphic to a closed disc) that I want to behave as a portal. Each side of $\sigma$ should be glued to a different copy of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is only accessible by a path that intersects $\sigma$ from that side.

I've thought about how to construct such a space with quotient spaces, but the intuition of a quotient space doesn't seem  quite right. I've also considered gluing along the limit points of Cauchy sequences that come at $pq$ from a particular side, but that seems difficult to formalize. How would one go about formalizing this type of construction?

Comment: How about $(\mathbb R^2_{++} \sqcup \mathbb R^2_{+-}) \sqcup (\mathbb R^2_{-+} \sqcup \mathbb R^2_{--})$ modulo $\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $t_{++} \sim t_{+-}$ if $t \not\in (p, q)$ and $t_{+\pm} \sim t_{-\pm}$ if $t \in (p, q)$?

Comment: This sentence: *The result will be the original* $\mathbb R^2$ *with two additional* $\mathbb R^2$ *glued along* $\overline{pq}$ *and* $\overline{qp}$--is not clear to me.

Comment: @LSpice Admittedly that's a good thought. By equating $\mathbb{R}_{++}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}_{+-}^2$ you're making two copies of $pq$ and then pasting each to a different copy of $pq$. I think this is roughly topologically equivalent to what I want, but it doesn't have the same geometric properties. In particular this notion of orientation on $pq$ such that entering from one side transports you to a different space than entering on the other.

Comment: Notice that I do *not* equate the two $\mathbb R^2_{+\pm}$.  Instead, I glue $t_{++}$ to $t_{+-}$ only if $t \not\in (p, q)$.  This "double all, then collapse most" approach has the effect of doubling just $(p, q)$, so that you can tell on which 'side' you entered it.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński I want to remove the relative interior of $pq$ and consider the oriented paths $\overrightarrow{pq}$ and $\overrightarrow{qp}$. Along each path I want to glue a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus the result is three copies of $\mathbb{R}^2$ glued along $pq$.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, equate probably wasn't the right word, but I did understand what you meant. This still doesn't have the geometric property that entering $pq$ from one direction, say from the left, only allows you to enter a specific $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $\mathbb{R}_{--}$. It seems as though this construction allows you to enter either upon arriving at $pq$, depending on which copy of $pq$ you choose to enter from and not from the direction.

Comment: Oh, or did you mean that *any* path from, say, 'above' $(p, q)$ enters one $\mathbb R^2$, and any path from 'below' enters the other?  (EDIT:  Yes, you did: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/186430/creating-topological-spaces-with-portals#comment466014_186430 .)  Then write $\mathbb R^2 = H_+ \cup H_-$, and glue $(H_+ \sqcup H_-) \sqcup (\mathbb R^2_+ \sqcup \mathbb R^2_-)$ as before.

Comment: That does look like it gets what I want, thank you! However is there an easy generalization to $\mathbb{R}^3$ where I'm no longer glueing along a line segment (which allows me to consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the union of hyperplanes meeting at $pq$) but instead want to allow an arbitrary smooth orientable patch of surface (something homeomorphic to a closed disc) to act as a portal?

Comment: I should clarify, a surface that does not necessarily lie entirely within a hyperplane.

Comment: The whole geometric concept doesn't seem correct. First a formall possible overstatement: **three copies of* $\mathbb R^2$? or just two of them added to a *ring*. A formal definition of the space would help. Do you want to start with $\ \mathbb C\setminus D,\ $ where $D$ is the open unit ball (disc) in the complex $\mathbb C$ around $0$ (and then you'd add two copies of an open disc glued to the upper and lower semi-circle boundary of $D$? What exactly would happen at the end-point of the paths: $\ -\!1\ 1\in\mathbb C$? How would be the neighborhood of the result around $\ -\!1\ 1$?

Comment: [Crossposted to MSE.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1009663/98602)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment at [Creating topological spaces with portals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186430/creating-topological-spaces-with-portals#comment466017_186430), I think that I may have an answer.  However, it seems to me that you are asking me to capture the right intuitive generalisation of a concept that you have given only for $\mathbb R^2$; so, if it doesn't fit what you want, then I hope you'll give at least another example.

I think that the general idea is that you want to choose a subset $P$ of a topological space $X$, and glue 3 copies of $X$ along $P$ in such a way that entering $P$ at its 'left' side on the 'original' $X$ goes into the 'left new' $X$, and similarly on the right.

To that end, choose two subsets $H_+$ and $H_-$ of $X$ (probably you want them in $\operatorname{cl}(\complement P)$) such that $H_+ \cup H_- \cup P = X$.  (As with the overlap at $p$ and $q$ in your example, we do not require the various sets to be disjoint.)  Then "$X$ with portal $P$ *via* $H_+$ and $H_-$" is defined to be $(H_+ \sqcup H_- \sqcup P) \sqcup (X_+ \sqcup X_-)$, modulo glueing $H_+$, $H_-$, and $P$ along their pairwise intersections, $H_\pm$ pointwise to its copy in $X_\pm$, and $P$ to its copy in each $X_\pm$.

EDIT:  Corrected the glueing.

Comment: Can you clarify the notation $CP$ in $\operatorname{cl}CP$?

Comment: @user61430, it's `\complement`.

Comment: Yes, I do believe this answers my question. Thank you!